# On-screen directions in UI: telling users to do the obvious

Tags: usability, interface, accessibility, content

Should we include directions to a user in the UI content that tells them to do something that is visually obvious?

For example, we inform users that they need to verify their device. Text includes "Click Verify to get started," where there is a button below with the word Verify on it.

In favor of the text: including the obvious instruction makes the UI content more accessible, as a screen reader picks up the "Click Verify..." text so that a non-sighted user knows what to do.

Others say that the design should be so intuitive that no directions are needed.

Any standards out there that should apply?

Comment: can you include a mock of your specific efforts so far? So much in UX depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

Google does a very good job at providing an explanation for this.

[Web Accessibility](https://webaccessibility.withgoogle.com/unit?unit=6&lesson=9)

Now this is wrapped around how to code it with ARIA but the approach is solid.

Another way to think about this is that screen readers will read everything on the screen that it can detect. This includes button names.  So if you have a line of text that says click to verify and a button that says the same thing you have to consider what hearing the direction twice will do to the usability of your site for those that need to leverage accessibility technologies.  So keep things clear visually and only provide the instruction once, preferably on the button itself so that everyone gets the same relative quality of experience.

Comment: Thanks, very good point about repeating the instructions - I see how it could create an issue for a screen reader if it detects the word "verify" twice.